# Jersey error after migrating EAR from Jboss EAP 6.4 to Jboss EAP 7.3

Tags: java, jboss7.x, resteasy, jboss6.x, jersey-1.0

Recently i migrated a jboss eap 6.4 application to jboss eap 7.3.

The application uses resteasy and jersey(1.9.1) for some service implementations.

Since resteasy is automatically loaded by jboss, i have excluded that from the deployment using the following confis in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<exclusions>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.async-http-servlet-30" />
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />         
</exclusions>
```

Also following parameters are set in the REST service war file web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

What I can not figure out is, i'm getting this following error

```
    22 Oct 2020 01:01:49,354 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] - MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxxxx_0.ear"."xxxREST.war".undertow-deployment
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."xxxxxx_0.ear"."xxxREST.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Initialized Extension not found
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Initialized Extension not found
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtensionFromBeanManager(CDIExtension.java:196)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:180)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
```

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some tips to solve this problem :)

Comment: What CDI implementation are you using ?

Comment: I'm using resteasy-cdi library version 3.9.3.SP1